# Avoiding JOIN to increase performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, key

Lets say I have users table:

| id | username | email | address |

And posts table:
| id | post | user_id | date |

When I want to show posts, each time I need to go users table to retrieve username from user_id. I want to avoid using JOIN for this simple data retreive so what I do is adding another coloumn to posts table:
| id | post | user_id | username | date |

This way I will not have to use JOIN to retreive username when showing posts

Do you think that this is better?

Comment: There is no reason to avoid simple inner joins.  If you put a foreign key index on `user_id`, there will be no noticeable performance hit at all for the join.  Mysql is built for this kind of thing.

Comment: What about performance with multiple (3-4) Joins?

Comment: If they are all indexed joins, then no, there is still almost no performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

no. your alternative structure is vulnerable to inconsistencies (e.g. if a user changes his name; read about 3rd Normal form here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form#.22Nothing_but_the_key.22)
why don't you want to use JOINs? have you set up approriate indexes?

Comment: I do not want to use JOINS becasue I need every bit of improved performace. I know that the query will run many many times.

Comment: DO you think using JOINS with indexes will not be slow?

Comment: see comment by spsc_tech above. you could also look into your current query_cache configuration to increase performance. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

Comment: Joins are what relational databases are designed to do. What are you trying to do, run the query a hundred times a second?  At that rate, it'll be the connection speed between your code and the database that makes the performance difference, not the query itself.  On my business's systems, the performance depends 99% on the size of the result being fetched, because there is a bandwidth and PHP memory bottleneck. Ex.: query with 20 joins and 100 results takes 0.003 seconds, query with 0 joins and 100 results takes < 0.001 seconds, both take 0.3 seconds to fetch all 100 results.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the design and future, niy I will suggest you not to do that:
although from present respect, you will think it will be better performance to avoid join, but what if your application expand, and it is no good to use this unnormalized table structure.

For instance, if one of the poster changed username, how could you achieve that? to update the whole table? if your data could exccess 10Million tuples, it will be tough because `update` will lock the table in the process of updating.
thus I will not recommend this.

Join performance can be omit if your application needs frequently updating in that way.

Comment: Yes the plan was to update the table. However I agree with you that it will need to update large tables, my compromise is assuming that this will not happend to often (unlike retreiving username for every post)

Answer (score 0):

If the `[id]` of `[users]` table is the primary key, I think it is good enough to use `JOIN`.

Alternatively, if you select limited number of `posts`, such as 10 posts, can also try this sql:

```
select id, post, user_id, 
    (select username from users where id = user_id) as username, date
from posts
limit 0, 10
```